# Multiple dependent WCF service

Tags: wcf

Is there a way where I can create a set of wcf services where one service depends upon the request of the previous service?

That is, I create Service1, Service2, Service3.

Service2 should be invoked when the request of Service1 arrives.
Similarly, Service3 should be invoked when the request of Service2 arrives.
The response would then travel back from the Serice3 to Service2 then to Service1.

If this is not feasible, what is the nearest thing that is possible?
Kindly provide links to tutorials if you can.

Thanks

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by this line "Service2 should be invoked when the response of Service1 arrives. Similarly, Service3 should be invoked based on Service2 response." However, you can create 3/4/5 as many as you want WCF services and the first one will call its next and so on until the request reaches to the last WCF service then the response will travel back to the first service. I dont know where would be application of this scenario though.

Comment: _"Kindly provide links to tutorials if you can."_ - that's off-topic for SO

Comment: However, I do recommend the SOA books by Thomas Erl

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but chaining service calls together in this manner is not a good design.